# NLTK Import error: module 'nltk' has no attribute 'py'

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have already downloaded NLTK. The next step is to run python and type import nltk and then nltk.download(). When I run IDLE with import nltk, I should see a new window pop up but instead this is the output I receive.

```
=============== RESTART: /Users/laila/Documents/howboutnow.py ===============
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/laila/Documents/howboutnow.py", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "/Users/laila/Documents/nltk.py", line 3, in <module>
    nltk.py.download()
AttributeError: module 'nltk' has no attribute 'py'
```

For reference, this is the video I've been following to download and use NLTK.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLZvOKSCkxY&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDf2JswnfiGkliBInZnIC4HL
I use a 64 bit MacBook Air and have both version 2.7 and 3.4 of Python on my laptop.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: nltk.py.download() should be nltk.download(). Time 7:08 on the video

Comment: This is the output when I changed nltk.py.download() to nltk.download().                                   ================== RESTART: /Users/laila/Documents/nltk.py ==================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/laila/Documents/nltk.py", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "/Users/laila/Documents/nltk.py", line 3, in <module>
    nltk.download()
AttributeError: module 'nltk' has no attribute 'download'

Comment: rename your file nltk.py to something else like my_nltk.py and run again.

Comment: Output was as follows:                                                                   ================= RESTART: /Users/laila/Documents/my_nltk.py =================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/laila/Documents/my_nltk.py", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "/Users/laila/Documents/nltk.py", line 3, in <module>
    nltk.download()
AttributeError: module 'nltk' has no attribute 'download'

Comment: Delete this file "/Users/laila/Documents/nltk.py"

Comment: import nltk is to import the installed nltk module but since you have a file named nltk.py on the same folder the import is importing this file and that's where the problem happens. You should never name your file the same as a python module

Comment: It worked!!!! Thank you so much!! My programming teacher who has been working with Python for 5-6 years couldn't even figure it out. I can't thank you enough, I seriously appreciate it! I've had this problem for 3 weeks now and only now, a wave of relief rushes over me knowing it's solved. Thank you many times over Atirag!

Comment: Glad I could help :) Also you should get a new teacher ;)

Comment: I'll make you my go-to ;) (jokes)